Identify if there is a contiguous group of non-zeros in a list
I have a list of integers. I want to know if the non-zero numbers form a single contiguous group. So for instance:
[0, 0, -1, 2, -3, 0] True
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0] True
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0] True
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] True
[0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3] False
[1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 0] False
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] False

My code that produced the above:
def simple_contiguous_subset(data):
    if all(x == 0 for x in data): # drop this line and next if all 0 should be True
        return False
    seen_zero_after_group = False
    in_non_zero_group = False
    for num in data:
        if num == 0:
            if not in_non_zero_group:
                seen_zero_after_group = False
            else:
                seen_zero_after_group = True
        else:
            if seen_zero_after_group:
                return False
            in_non_zero_group = True
    return True


data_list = [[0,0,-1,2,-3,0], [1,2,3,0,0,0], [1,2,3,4,5,0], [1,1,1,1,1,1], [0,1,0,3,3,3], [1,2,3,0,3,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0]]
for data in data_list:
    result = simple_contiguous_subset(data)
    print(f"{data} {result}")

I'm just wondering if there's a faster more direct way. I've struggled a bit with itertools.groupby but not making any headway.

Realise that itertools.groupby also loops...

There's nothing in itertools that would look any better than a simple function using a for-loop.

"I've struggled a bit with itertools.groupby but not making any headway." Hint: if all the non-zeros are contiguous, how many groups of consecutive non-zeros are there? If they aren't, what can you say about the number of groups?

What's [0,0,0,0,0,0] supposed to be (True or False)?

@ Karl Knechtel If there's more than one group of non-zeros then by definition of the problem the result is False. Even if "group" means one item.

Given the list lst:
it = iter(lst)
result = any(it) and (all(it) or not any(it))

That tests that there is a non-zero and that that's either followed only by non-zeros or (if there is a zero after it) that there's no second group of non-zeros.
Stops as early as possible, doesn't go through the whole list if a second group of non-zeros is found early.
Attempt This Online!
Benchmark with your lists and a few more solutions:
 0.77 ± 0.01 μs  baseline
 2.10 ± 0.04 μs  Stefan_4
 2.10 ± 0.05 μs  Stefan_3
 2.37 ± 0.17 μs  Stefan_1
 3.63 ± 0.12 μs  Stefan_2
 8.27 ± 0.41 μs  inspectorG4dget
 8.79 ± 0.56 μs  Jasmijn

Python: 3.12.0 (main, Oct  7 2023, 10:42:35) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801]

And with just one list ([0] * 1000 + list(range(1000))) * 2:
  0.7 ±  0.0 μs  baseline
 31.9 ±  0.1 μs  Stefan_1
 60.1 ±  1.0 μs  Stefan_3
 85.3 ±  1.9 μs  Stefan_4
114.9 ±  2.5 μs  inspectorG4dget
115.1 ±  3.1 μs  Jasmijn
127.0 ±  2.5 μs  Stefan_2

And with just one list [0, 1] * 1000:
  0.6 ±  0.0 μs  baseline
  0.9 ±  0.0 μs  Stefan_4
  0.9 ±  0.0 μs  Stefan_3
  1.0 ±  0.0 μs  Stefan_1
  1.1 ±  0.0 μs  Stefan_2
358.3 ±  3.9 μs  Jasmijn
414.5 ±  8.4 μs  inspectorG4dget

Code:
def Stefan_1(lst):
    it = iter(lst)
    return any(it) and (all(it) or not any(it))

def Stefan_2(lst):
    it = map(bool, lst)
    return True in it and (False not in it or True not in it)

def Stefan_3(lst):
    it = iter(lst)
    for x in it:
        if x:
            for x in it:
                if not x:
                    for x in it:
                        if x:
                            return False
                    return True
            return True
    return False

def Stefan_4(lst):
    had_nonzero = had_zero_after_nonzero = False
    for x in lst:
        if x:
            if had_zero_after_nonzero:
                return False
            had_nonzero = True
        elif had_nonzero:
            had_zero_after_nonzero = True
    return had_nonzero
        
def Jasmijn(list_of_integers):
    return sum(1 for k, g in itertools.groupby(list_of_integers, key=bool) if k) == 1

def inspectorG4dget(L):
    groups = itertools.groupby(L, bool)
    k,group = next(groups)  # hold onto that first chunk - we're gonna need it later
    numGroups = sum(k for k,g in groups)  # count up the number of non-0 chunks
    if numGroups+k > 1: return False  # >2 non-0 chunks in total
    if numGroups == 1: return True  # 2 chunks total
    return k  # if it's a non-0 group, this returns `True`; `False` otherwise (i.e. all 0s)

def baseline(lst):
    return False

funcs = [
    baseline,
    Stefan_1, Stefan_2, Stefan_3, Stefan_4,
    Jasmijn, inspectorG4dget
]

import itertools
from itertools import groupby
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
import sys
import random

tests = [
    [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0],
    [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3],
    [1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 3],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]

for f in funcs:
    print(*map(int, map(f, tests)))

times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e6 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):5.2f} ± {stdev(ts):4.2f} μs '
for _ in range(25):
    random.shuffle(funcs)
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: list(map(f, tests)), number=10**4) / 1e4
        times[f].append(t)
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)

print('\nPython:', sys.version)

Attempt This Online!

this is very interesting. I like it

@MikeP Also seems fast, as I had expected. See the added benchmarks.

I had just posted my naive approach in response the downvote complaints before I saw your update. Mine looks very similar to Stefan_4, though not as elegant. So if I read these results right, the simple approach of Stefan_4 is actually the fastest except with strange data (lot's of leading zeros)?

When I run your code, Stefan_1 is consistently fastest with my sample data. Which is what you expected.

@MikeP I certainly expected Stefan_1 to be fast at least for large lists with long runs like in my middle benchmark. For short lists or short runs, I wasn't so sure, I had to measure. Function calls can take significant time, so it can be faster to do raw basic iteration like Stefan_3 and Stefan_4.

Alright:

Use itertools.groupby to find contiguous 0- and non-0 chunks (non-0 is truthy, so bool should make things easier here).
Count the number chunks that are non-0
If there's more than one such chunk, return False
If there's exactly two chunks, return True
If there's exactly one chunk, return True if that chunk is non-0, False otherwise

def contiguousNonZero(L):
    groups = itertools.groupby(L, bool)
    k,group = next(groups)  # hold onto that first chunk - we're gonna need it later
    numGroups = sum(k for k,g in groups)  # count up the number of non-0 chunks
    if numGroups+k > 1: return False  # >2 non-0 chunks in total
    if numGroups == 1: return True  # 2 chunks total
    return k  # if it's a non-0 group, this returns `True`; `False` otherwise (i.e. all 0s)

Testing:
In [214]: tests = [[0,0,1,2,3,0], [1,2,3,0,0,0], [1,2,3,4,5,0], [1,1,1,1,1,1], [0,1,0,3,3,3], [1,2,3,0,3,3], [0,0,0,0,0,0]]

In [215]: for t in tests: print(contiguousNonZero(t))
True
True
True
True
False
False
False


this works for me in two ways. it solves the problem and it gives me something to study. i can't yet figure out HOW  it works!

Why not simply use something like return sum(k for k, g in itertools.groupby(L, bool)) == 1?

@Jasmijn I was trying to be very explicit in my logic. To your point, return sum(k for k, _g in itertools.groupby(L, bool)) == 1 will work just fine

Given list_of_integers, this would solve your problem:
sum(1 for k, g in itertools.groupby(list_of_integers, key=bool) if k) == 1

Now, I think this is rather cryptic and I recommend just going with a for-loop. Don't be tempted to make your code too clever.
Here's my explanation:
groups = itertools.groupby(list_of_integers, key=bool)

Groups the integers in such a way that all consecutive 0s go in their own groups and all consecutive non-0s go in other groups.
non_zeroes = [1 for k, g in groups if k]

This creates a list of 1s, one 1 for every group of consecutive non-0s (k == bool(next(g))). (In my one liner, I use a generator expression instead, but you can use either one.)
sum(non_zeroes) == 1

This checks if the total of them is 1. If you use a list comprehension rather than a generator expression, you could also have done len(non_zeroes) == 1. Dealer's choice.
